# Scrape data from xmlhttp

Tags: html, vba, http, web-scraping, scrape

I'm trying to scrape elements from xmlhttp.
I'm not too bad with vba, but relatively new to data scraping.
I have previously been using ie.

I can import the html into a cell, but would like to import specifically, the name, id, price and stock level.

The code I'm using to import the data is

```
    Private Sub HTML_VBA_Excel()

    Dim oXMLHTTP    As Object
    Dim sPageHTML   As String
    Dim sURL        As String

        'Change the URL before executing the code
        sURL = "https://www.superdrug.com/Make-Up/Lips/Lip-Kits/Flower-Beauty-Mix-N%27-Matte-Lipstick-Duo-Tickled-Pink-687/p/769466"

        'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
        Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
        oXMLHTTP.send
        sPageHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText

        'Get webpage data into Excel
        sh02.Cells(1, 1) = sPageHTML

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help received.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract the information reliably from an xmlhttp request issued against the url you show as the content is javascript loaded and will not have run.

Not sure how sustainable the token is (doesn't seem to matter the value used) but you can join the productid, which is the end of your url, with the ajax token present in the page and issue and xmlhttp request using querystring parameters and parse a json response for the items of interest. I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After downloading and installing the .bas you need to go `VBE > Tools > References` and add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

Some testing seems to indicate any number can be added after the hyphen in place of the token so you could randomly generate a number on the fly to use.

It's worth noting you can comma separate multiple products in the query string and thus do a bulk request. You would need then do a `For Each` Loop over the collection of dictionaries returned.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.superdrug.com/micrositeProduct/bulk/769466-1548702898380"
    Dim json As Object, title As String, price As String, stocking As String, id As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        Set json = jsonconverter.ParseJson(.responsetext)(1)
    End With

    title = json("name")
    price = json("price")("formattedValue") 'json("price")("value")
    stocking = json("stockLevel")
    id = json("code")
End Sub
```

If you use a browser then the json string is present within one the script tags as the `.innerHTML` and you can easily extract from there.

Comment: Thanks again QHarr. What variables do i need to use for this? jsonconverter as object & writetxtfile  and responsetext as strings?     Think my "Ok" vba skill is very much relative here.  Thanks.  Ian

Comment: All the variables are in there. You need to download the jsonconverter.bas from the provided link. I didn't mean to include the writetxt line.